# Performance and Media player OS for old Pi model B

Tags: performance, openelec, pi-1, libreelec

I want to replace my old OSes (RaspBMC and Libreelec8) for Raspberry pi B by a more modern distribution but I also I want to ensure that the performance is not much worse.
As modern distributions probably are focusing in raspberry pi3 or 4, models with much higher hardware specs than Pi Model B.

Which Distribution and configuration you recommend for the the Raspberry pi1 (ARM11-700Mhz,512MB SDRAM) ?

What is the scenario of older pi models, performance and modern distributions?

Comment: Sorry, but opinion based questions are [off topic](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask).

Comment: @Unsigned_Arduino  i just removed the word "opinion", so now it is only about facts proved scientifically ;)  Although more 95% of messages in stackoverflow are just opinions of altruist users.

Comment: True true true... (if this question gets closed, maybe you should ask it at the [Software Recommendations Stack Exchange](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/).)

Comment: Why not try something?  A days 'playing' will teach lots.  Chance of a %age figure coming is so so low a secret Santa with Pi 5 specs are more likely :-)  voting close for opinions.

Comment: @Andyroo I have been trying but I can spend weeks trying every possible option, distribution and configuration to acquire the "complete" knowledge. Whereas other users have more knowledge and experience and can share with me and community.